# Create pairs of nodes from an XML file

Tags: c#, xml, selectnodes

I have an ´OrderList´ with multipile ´OrderInfo´. Each ´OrderInfo´ has only one ´Documentcode´ and maximum four ´Documentid´. How can I find which DocumentId belongs to which Documentcode? I have the following xml:

```
<OrderList>
    <OrderInfo>
        <DocList>
            <DocumentInfo>
                <Documentid>12</Documentid> 
            </DocumentInfo>
            <DocumentInfo>
                <Documentid>22</Documentid> 
            </DocumentInfo>
        </DocList>
        <Documentcode>ABC2</Documentcode> 
   </OrderInfo>
   <OrderInfo>
        <DocList>
            <DocumentInfo>
                <Documentid>11</Documentid> 
            </DocumentInfo>
            <DocumentInfo>
                <Documentid>25</Documentid> 
            </DocumentInfo>
        </DocList>
        <Documentcode>ABC3</Documentcode> 
   </OrderInfo>
```

with:

```
var documentId = myXml.SelectNodes("/OrderList/OrderInfo/DocList/DocumentInfo/Documentid");
```

I get the total number of Documentid's. But how can I loop inside ´OrderInfo´ and find out the pairs "Documentcode"-´DocumentId´? For example:

```
ABC2=12
ABC2=22
ABC3=11
ABC3=25
```

If I have this I can create Dictionaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this little piece of Linq , it may not be very resilient against missing levels/elements.

```
var doc = XElement.Load(fileName);

Dictionary<string, string> dic = doc
     .Descendants("Documentid")
     .ToDictionary(e => e.Value, 
                   e => e.Parent.Parent.Parent.Element("Documentcode").Value );

 // verify
 Console.WriteLine(dic["12"]);
 Console.WriteLine(dic["25"]);
```